# DateTimeFormatter with parseDefaulting throwing exception

Tags: java, datetimeformatter, datetimeparseexception

I have

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_PATTERN = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[ ]['T'][HH:mm:ss][.SSSSSS][.SSSSS][.SSSS][.SSS][.SS][.S][X]")
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC); // assume incoming is UTC
```

used by

```
public static Function<String, String> getFormattedDate() {
  return dateTime -> {
    try {
      ZonedDateTime timeRemoved =
          ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, DATE_PATTERN).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
      return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DISPLAY_DATE_PATTERN).format(timeRemoved);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

with a test that fails

```
public void test_data_patter_with_ms(){
  String formattedDate = DateTimeUtil.getFormattedDate().apply("2021-04-24T06:57:06.850");
  assertThat(formattedDate, is("2021-04-24T00:00:00Z"));
}
```

with the exception

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text
> '2021-04-24T06:57:06.850' could not be parsed: Conflict found:
> NanoOfSecond 850000000 differs from NanoOfSecond 0 while resolving
> MilliOfSecond

If I comment out .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0) it works, but I'm not really sure I understand why and I don't like fixing issues and not understanding the why I fixed it.

Comment: You only need to default `ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY`, you can leave out minutes seconds and millis since they already have default 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `S` pattern specifier corresponds to the `NANO_OF_SECOND` field. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S | fraction-of-second | fraction | 978 |

> The count of pattern letters determines the format.
>
> **Fraction:** Outputs the nano-of-second field as a fraction-of-second. The nano-of-second value has nine digits, thus the
> count of pattern letters is from 1 to 9. If it is less than 9, then
> the nano-of-second value is truncated, with only the most significant
> digits being output.

Therefore, when you do `parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0)`, the default value 0 is *always* used. From the documentation of [`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting(java.time.temporal.TemporalField,long)):

> During parsing, the current state of the parse is inspected. If the specified field has no associated value, because it has not been parsed successfully at that point, then the specified value is injected into the parse result.

In your case, it is always the case that `MILLI_OF_SECOND` "has no associated value", because your pattern parses the `NANO_OF_SECOND` field. There is no `MILLI_OF_SECOND` component in your pattern in the first place!

And only then comes the *resolution* step of the parsing process. This basically figures out the values of unknown fields from the known fields, and also checks that the values of the fields agree with each other. This is where the algorithm finds out that somehow your date has a `MILLI_OF_SECOND` of 0 due to your `parseDefaulting` call, but also a `NANO_OF_SECOND` of 850000000 because of what's in your string. This is a contradiction, and so an exception is thrown.

I think you should have called `parseDefaulting` with `NANO_OF_SECOND` instead:

```
.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)
```

This way, when any of the `.SSS` options appear in the string, the default value won't be used.

Side note:

It is possible to change your pattern so that it parses the `MILLI_OF_SECOND` field, using `appendValue`:

```
var dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd[ ]['T'][HH:mm:ss]")
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral('.')
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 1, 3, SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD)
    .optionalEnd()
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

// note that in this case the milliseconds are not understood as a fraction, but a number
// 2021-04-24T06:57:06.001Z
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-04-24T06:57:06.1", dtf));

// parseDefaulting works
// 2021-04-24T06:57:06.000Z
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-04-24T06:57:06", dtf));
```

Comment: what you say makes sense, but further down the documentation I see n nano-of-second number 987654321
N nano-of-day number 1234000000

Comment: @DanOConnell Are you asking about the difference between `n` and `S`? Well, the difference is that `n` is a number, whereas `S` is a fraction, like the part after the decimal point. For example, "123" means different things for `n` and `S`. For `S`, "123" means 123000000 nanoseconds (0.123 seconds), whereas for `n`, "123" just means 123 nanoseconds. And `N` is the nanosecond of the *day*, not of the second, so it is a completely different thing.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a removal of nanos like

```java
.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 0)
```

Link to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#NANO_OF_SECOND)

Also I recommend to switch to LocalDate which is way more helpful on comparing and formatting dates ;)